# Invalid Fingerprint generation when is salesforce integrated with nab transact

Tags: encryption, salesforce, payment-gateway, sha1, apex

I have integrated salesforce and nab transact for payment purpose. I created fingerprint in my visualforce page using javascript. Now for security reasons I need to change this from visualforce page to my apex controller. I have the following code for the same.

```
String hashv= nabname+'|'+nabpass+ '|2|'+paymentId+'|'+ amtT + '|' + now_utc; 
String targetString =hashv ;
Blob targetBlob = Blob.valueOf(targetString);
Blob hashSHA1 = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', targetBlob);
String hashBase64SHA1 = EncodingUtil.base64encode(hashSHA1);
```

"hashBase64SHA1" variable is assigned to the fringerprint field in my vf page. This gives me invalid Fingerprint error. Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
String shasign =
    EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1',Blob.valueOf(hashv)));
```